# "the necessity therefore"

Tags: interpretation, legal-terms

I am reading a law reference book and finding this line somewhat ambiguous.

> If the Grantor timely objects to any disbursement, or the reasonableness thereof, or the necessity **therefore**, no such disbursement or similar disbursement shall be made in the future, except on notice to the Grantor. ([source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Structured_Settlements_and_Periodic_Paym/Wqt0EP889hoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22on%20notice%20to%22&pg=PP451&printsec=frontcover))

To me "the necessity therefore" is a source of confusion. Shouldn't it be "the necessity *thereof*" since it refers to the necessity of the *disbursement*? Or am I misreading this line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be better on English.SE since it is really just about the meaning of English words, and there are several related questions on that site.

I think *therefore* is a spelling error and they meant to write *[therefor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58616/is-there-a-difference-between-therefor-and-therefore/58617#58617)*.  *Therefor* means "for that", just as *thereof* means "of that".  If so, then sentence could be rephrased:

> If the Grantor timely objects to any disbursement, or the reasonableness **of** the disbursement, or the necessity **for** the disbursement, ...

There might be a grammatical debate as to whether it should be "necessity **for** the disbursement" or "necessity **of** the disbursement".  In the latter case, you could write "the necessity **thereof**".  But in either case, it clearly means "whether the disbursement was necessary".

Answer (score 3):

In this context, the meaning of "the necessity therefore" and "the necessity thereof" would be identical. Both constructions are less than ideal forms of legal drafting and a bit archaic.

Comment: But "therefore" is clearly a misspelling. It should say "therefor".